# Set cache to a specific path with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla3.0

Recently I am dealing with apache over load issues from the request that causes the website.

I have read till now apache has a performance lack if you enable the global .htaccess overwrite settings. If you enable it apache will search in every folder of the website for .htaccess overwrites, this will slow down my server

As my websites are running in Joomla I was wondering 
1- How can I tell apache to just read the JOOMLA_ROOT/.htaccess file
2- From the Joomla .htaccess file how can I set the expire time of the JOOMLA_ROOT/cache folder.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow - you might be better off asking over at [sf]. That said, you should probably stick to doing your configuration in the server config itself.

Comment: Why do you think that `.htaccess` lookup is causing your server load issues? Did you measure it? What exactly is happening?

Comment: I am not an expert to measure it, but everywhere I have read about this was not a good idea to let AllowOverride on in dedicated servers. Here you can read something about it https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html